# C: implicit declaration of function ‘getpwnam_r’

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

While retrieving the broken-out fields of the record in the password database (e.g., the local password file `/etc/passwd`, NIS, and LDAP) that matches a provided username name, I am using the `getpwnam_r` (**http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam_r**) function.

```
#define __USE_BSD
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct passwd pwd;
    struct passwd *result;
    char *buf;
    size_t bufsize;
    int s;

   if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s username\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   bufsize = sysconf(_SC_GETPW_R_SIZE_MAX);
    if (bufsize == -1)          /* Value was indeterminate */
        bufsize = 16384;        /* Should be more than enough */

   buf = malloc(bufsize);
    if (buf == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   s = getpwnam_r(argv[1], &pwd, buf, bufsize, &result);
    if (result == NULL) {
        if (s == 0)
            printf("Not found\n");
        else {
            errno = s;
            perror("getpwnam_r");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("Name: %s; UID: %ld\n", pwd.pw_gecos, (long) pwd.pw_uid);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The code works fine, but Eclipse shows me a warning as follows:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getpwnam_r’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

How could I fix it?

Note that I'm currently using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

Comment: Is there any reason you chose not to `#include <sys/types.h>`?

Comment: as defined in `pwd.h`, `getpwnam_r` is POSIX only

Comment: I'm not getting this error in Eclipse (on OS X) with the CDT plugin. How have you defined your project? (Sorry I don't use Eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use this function you need two includes :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
```

Add them and it should not complain anymore.

You can see that by running [`man getpwnam_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html).

You also need to define either `__USE_MISC` or `__USE_SVID` since it a POSIX only function.